# Get Scala variable name at runtime

Tags: scala

Is it possible to get the name of a scala variable at runtime?

E.g. is it possible to write a function `getIntVarName(variable: Int): String` behaving as follows?

```
val myInt = 3
assert("myInt" === getIntVarName(myInt))
```

Comment: @KingCrunch - It comes in very handy when you want to log stuff for debugging purposes, of for converting an object to a map or some other dynamic structure to be used with ORM frameworks and similar.

Comment: is it possible to do this in the REPL? Say `def foo(i:Int) = ValueOf("res"+i)`, ValueOf being the hypothetical function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, it can't be done.

The JVM offers nothing by way of a Method handle (remember, Scala properties are encoded as methods in bytecode to support the uniform access principle).  The closest you can get is to use reflection to find a list of methods defined on a particular class - which I appreciate doesn't help with your particular need.

It *is* possible to implement this as a Scala feature, but it would require a compiler plugin to grab the relevant symbol name from the AST and push it into code as a string literal, so not something I could demonstrate in a short code snippet :)

The other naming problem that often comes up in reflection is method parameters.  That one at least I can help with.  I have a [work-in-progress reflection library here](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-reflect) that's based on the compiler-generated scala signature as used by `scalap`.  It's nowhere near being ready for serious use, but it is under active development.

Comment: And now (with Scala 2.11), is it possible to get a variable name or instance name using the Scala reflection API ? How can we achieve that ?

Comment: @metch have a look at my answer down the page. Is it what you needed?

Answer (score 15):

For what you need to do, It seems to me that runtime is not required, since you already have your myInt variable defined at compile time. If this is the case, you just need a bit of AST manipulation via a macro.

Try

```
package com.natalinobusa.macros

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object Macros {

  // write macros here
  def getName(x: Any): String = macro impl

  def impl(c: Context)(x: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val p = x match {
      case Select(_, TermName(s)) => s
      case _ => ""
    }
    q"$p"
  }
}
```

Be aware that macro's must be compiled as a separate subproject, and cannot be part of the same project where the macro substitution has to be applied. Check this template on how to define such a macro sub-project: https://github.com/echojc/scala-macro-template

```
scala> import Macros._
import Macros._

scala> val myInt = 3
myInt: Int = 3

scala> "myInt" == getName(myInt)
res6: Boolean = true
```

Comment: In scala interpreter this code works, then I switched to my Intellij idea  IDE and even though I am using scala 2.11.8 I get compiling error on "TermName" and "q". Should I do something special for using scala macros in my IDE?

Comment: Hi @M.Rez macros must not be part of the same project using the macro. Have you checked this project for reference? https://github.com/echojc/scala-macro-template

Comment: In particular, look at the build.scala, the interpreter indeed does not need separate projects. But the compiler needs to add the macro in its context, before parsing the code, that's why the macros are a separate project.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [scala-nameof](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof) to get a variable name, function name, class member name, or type name. It happens at compile-time so there's no reflection involved and no runtime dependency needed.

```
val myInt = 3
assert("myInt" === nameOf(myInt))
```

will compile to:

```
val myInt = 3
assert("myInt" === "myInt")
```

Comment: will you please make the package available for scala 2.13

Answer (score 2):

Scala doesn't yet have much more than Java in terms of metadata like this.  Keep an eye on the [Scala Reflection project](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-reflect), but I doubt that will offer access to local variables anytime soon.  In the meantime, consider a bytecode inspector library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).  Another big caveat: local variable names are lost during compilation, so you'd need to compile in "debug" mode to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to get the name of a variable, but you can try it with objects:

```
object Test1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    object MyVar {
      def value = 1
    }
    println(MyVar.getClass)
  }
}
```

This prints: `class Test1$MyVar$2$`. So you can get 'MyVar' out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with **Scala 3** Macros (does it at compile time).

Create a Macro object (this must be in a separate file):

```
import scala.quoted.{Expr, Quotes}

object NameFromVariable :

  def inspectCode(x: Expr[Any])(using Quotes): Expr[String] =
    val name = x.show.split("""\.""").last
    Expr(name)
```

Then you need an `inline` method in your class.

```
inline def getIntVarName(inline x: Any): Any = ${ NameFromVariable.inspectCode('x) }
```

And use this method, like:

```
val myInt = 3
assert("myInt" === getIntVarName(myInt))
```

See the official documentation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/macros.html