# How to get the name of a nested object in Scala without its package name and without $?

Tags: scala

There is already [In Scala, how do I get the *name* of an `object` (not an instance of a class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995250/in-scala-how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-not-an-instance-of-a-class) but I have the following code:

```
package test

object A {
  object B {
    object C
  }
}

val tmp = A.B.C
```

I would like to get the string "A.B.C" from value `tmp` at runtime, so no package name and no $ since this is the same name used in pattern matching for the type.

I tried the following:

```
tmp.getClass.getSimpleName // leads to exception "Malformed class name"
tmp.getClass.getName // has package name and $ characters
tmp.getClass.getTypeName // the same
msg.getClass.getName.replace("$", ".") // we still have the package name
```

I want to get the exact same name as in the AST for pattern matching:

```
case A.B.C =>
```

Note that neither the package name nor the object names are fixed.

Comment: You cannot state that you want to «get the string "A.B.C"», and at the same time pattern match using it as it was a type («case A.B.C» - unquoted, so not a string).

Comment: sry I meant without the case and =>

Answer (score 0):

> we still have the package name

So remove it:

```
val cls = tmp.getClass
cls.getName.stripPrefix(cls.getPackage.getName + ".").stripSuffix("$").replace("$", ".")
```

(the suffix is because it's an `object`)

Comment: This returns ".A.B.C.". You should strip the prefix and postfix dots.

Answer (score 0):

```
package whatever.however 

import scala.util.matching.Regex

object O {
  object A {
    object B {
      object C
      object D
    }
  }

  def relativeType2String(a: Any): String = {
    s"^${ Regex.quote(this.getClass.getName)}(\\.|\\$$)?(.*?)(\\$$)?$$".r.replaceFirstIn(a.getClass.getName, "$2").replace('$', '.')
  }

  // println(typeStringRelativeToHere(tmp))
}


object Run extends App {
  val tmp = O.A.B.C
  println(O.relativeType2String(tmp))

  // or match on type  
  import O._
  def onType(t: Any) = t match {
    case A.B.C => println("it's A.B.C")
    case A.B.D => println("it's A.B.D")
  }
  val tmp2 = A.B.D
  onType(tmp)
  onType(tmp2)
}
```

outputs

```
[info] A.B.C                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[info] it's A.B.C                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[info] it's A.B.D
```

~
~