# Create a scala object and get the name of this object

Tags: scala

I made a list of feature list.
I want to train a model for each feature list to test which feature list is the best

Finally I want to save the model with the name of the feature list used... 
How to get this name???

I saw this post:
[In Scala, how do I get the *name* of an `object` (not an instance of a class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995250/in-scala-how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-not-an-instance-of-a-class)

But when I do:

```
featureList1.getClass.getName
```

I get:

```
String = [Ljava.lang.String;
```

I want to get

```
java.lang.String = featureList1$
```

Here is my code:

```
val featureList1 = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]
val featureList2 = ["feature1", "feature3", "feature4"]
val featureList3 = ["feature5", "feature6", "feature7"]

val liste_featureList_to_test = List(featureList1, featureList2, featureList3)

for (featureList <- liste_featureList_to_test) {
    model_RF = trainModel (train, featureList)
    nomFeaturesList = ?????
    model_RF.write.overwrite.save("models/" + nomFeaturesList)
}
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: `val featureList1 = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]` is not valid Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do it using *reflection* but why are you want to save feature lists using object field names? Just specify name for each feature list and save them by this name:

```
val featureList1 = "featureList1" -> List("feature1", "feature2", "feature3")
val featureList2 = "featureList2" -> List("feature1", "feature3", "feature4")
val featureList3 = "featureList3" -> List("feature5", "feature6", "feature7")

val liste_featureList_to_test = List(featureList1, featureList2, featureList3)

for ((name, featureList) <- liste_featureList_to_test) {
  model_RF = trainModel (train, featureList)
  model_RF.write.overwrite.save("models/" + name)
}
```