# How to Check if Variable exists in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to check if a variable is already defined/exists in scala or not. Lets say a function called checkVar do this operation:

```
var x = 10
```

checkVar(x) -> returns boolean True

checkVar(y) -> returns boolean False

I am asking this question because I want to create a mechanism to define a variable if it doesn't exist.

Comment: A variable always exists at runtime because that is checked during compilation. You cannot refer to a variable that doesn't exist and trying to do so would simply result in not being able to produce an executable.

Comment: You can't. `checkVar(y)` will be considered a bad token because `y` is not yet defined. The variable name is not kept after compilation.

Comment: I am really surprised by your comments. So there is no solution? What I want to do is to create a mechanism to define a variable if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it possible to use error-handling techniques to define the function?

Comment: weird idea, scala is a compiled langage ! What is your goal and your context ?

Comment: There might be 2 ways to get the name of a variable: You might use a macro, though I don't think this works outside the interpreter in Scala 2. In Scala 3 however using a macro works. The other way is using the scala-nameof (https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof)  Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5050682/2205089

Comment: if I have defined a `x` on outer block, when I invoke `checkVar(x)` from the inner block, what will the value return ? What if I defined `x` in`Object A`, from `Object B`, it will retrun true of false? if I define function like `def x = 1`, what should it return?

Comment: It seems a [X-Y probelm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), what's your **original** problem ?

Comment: The function is actually invisble/implicit. You can put your variable x into the function by doing `x`. If it exist it will compile and if doesn't exist it won't. This is actually the fastest solution - you will get your answer even before running your app!

Comment: As written, you're looking for a run-time solution to a compile-time problem, which doesn't make sense. I.e. the compiler checks if `y` is a valid variable and will give you an error, so you couldn't even run a program with `checkVar(y)` if `y` wasn't a variable. Maybe you could re-represent your problem as checking if a certain key is present in a Map. E.g. `var m = Map("x" -> 123)` and `def checkVar(name: String) = m.contains(name)`

Answer (score 3):

Variables only exist at compile time so you can't dynamically create or delete variables at runtime. So both `x` and `y` must be defined at compile time or else the compiler will reject the code.

What you can do is use `Option` to indicate whether a variable has a *value* or not:

```
def checkVar(v: Option[Int]) = v.nonEmpty

var x = Some(10)

checkVar(x) // True

val y = None

checkVar(y) // False

x = None

checkVar(x) // False
```